# Appropriate usage of C# event handlers

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, thread-safety, state-machine

I'm currently building a C# application which will automatically authenticate a user against certain network resources when they connect to specific wireless networks.

At the moment, I'm using the [Managed Wifi API](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) to discover when a user connects / disconnects from a wireless network. I have an event handler, so that when any of these activities occurs, one of my methods is called to inspect the current state of the wireless connection.

To manage the state of the application, I have another class which is called the "conductor", which performs the operations required to change the state of the application. For instance, when the wireless card connects to the correct network, the conductor needs to change the system state from "Monitoring" to "Authenticating". If authentication succeeds, the conductor needs to change the state to "Connected". Disconnection results in the "Monitoring" state again, and an authentication error results in an "Error" state. These state changes (if the user requests) can result in TrayIcon notifications, so the user knows that they are being authenticated.

My current idea involves having the method used to inspect the current state of the wireless call the "authenticate" or "disconnect" methods within the state manager. However, I'm not sure if this is an appropriate use of the event handler -- should it instead be setting a flag or sending a message via some form of IPC to a separate thread which will begin the authentication / disconnection process?

In addition to the event handler being able to request connection / disconnection, a user can also perform it via the tray icon. As a result, I need to ensure these background operations are not blocking the tray's interactions with the user.

Only one component should be able to request a change of the system state at any time, so I would need to use a mutex to prevent concurrent state changes. However, how I should synchronous the rest of these components is a slight mystery to me.

Any advice or literature I should read would be appriciated. I have no formal training in C# language, so I apologize if I've misstated anything.

EDIT: Most importantly, I want to verify that an event will be executed as a separate thread, so it cannot block the main UI. In addition, I want to verify that if I have an event handler subscribed to an event, it will handle events serially, not in parallel (so if the user connects and disconnects before the first connection event is processed, two state changes will not be occurring simultaneously).

Comment: Avoid over-thinking this.  Just generate an event and let your UI implement it by disabling the "Connect" button.  Automatic interlock *and* visual feedback.

Comment: Here are a couple of links for you. First, to synchronize everything, the Rhino Service Bus may help. http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-service-bus Second, here's a great primer on threading in .NET, starting with the basics and expanding to advanced topics: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/index.shtml

Answer (score 1):

> Any advice or literature I should read would be appriciated. I have no formal training in C# language, so I apologize if I've misstated anything.

That explains a few things. :)
I would read up on threads, event handling, and creation of system tray icons/interfaces.

It is important to note the following:

- Events are processed on the same thread they are called from.  If you want the processing of an event not to lock the GUI then you will need to have the button move the work to a different thread.
- When an event is fired it passes the appropriate arguments to all the methods in its list.  This is pretty much the same as calling one method which in turn calls all the others (see EventFired example).  The purpose of events is not to call methods as we can do that already, it is to call methods which may not be known when the code is compiled (the click event on a button control would not be known when the library the control is in is compiled for example).  In short, if you can call the method instead of using an event the do so.

  ```
  void EventFired(int arg1, object arg2)
  {
      subscribedMethod1(arg1, arg2);
      SubscribedMethod2(arg1, arg2);
      SubscribedMethod3(arg1, arg2);
      SubscribedMethod4(arg1, arg2);
      SubscribedMethod5(arg1, arg2);
      SubscribedMethod6(arg1, arg2);
      SubscribedMethod7(arg1, arg2);
  }
  ```
- If you want to prevent a user interface from locking do the work on another thread.  Remember though, user interface elements (forms, buttons, grids, labels, etc.) can only be accessed from their host thread.  Use the control.Invoke method to call methods on their thread.
- Removing an option from an interface is not a good way to prevent raceway conditions (the user starts a connect/disconnect while one is already running) as the user interface will be on a different thread and could be out of sync (it takes time for separate threads to sync up).  While there are many ways to resolve this problem, the easiest for someone new to threading is to use a lock on the value.  This way .NET will make sure only one thread can change the setting at a time.  You will still need to update the user interface so the user knows the update is occurring.

Your general design sound fine.  You could use 2-3 threads (1 for the user interface (tray icon), 1 for checking for new network connections, and 1 (could be merged with connection check) which checks the internet connection.

Hope this helps, let us know if you need more (or accept an answer).

Comment: "If you want the processing of an event not to lock the GUI then you will need to have the button move the work to a different thread". I recognize this from when I built a previous app -- clicking on the button would launch another thread, which would be stopped via a bool (I know you don't want to just abort another thread). However, the event which I'm discussing (`WlanNotificationEventHandler WlanNotification`), part of the `Managed Wifi Api` -- which thread will the methods which subscribe to this event run on? The "main" thread which controls my UI? Or a separate thread?

Comment: @BSchlinker  I expect it will run on the thread where you created the WlanClient instance.  The easiest way to tell know for certain is to put a break point on the first line of the method which has subscribed to the event, run the program and generate the event so the break point is hit, open the threads panel (Debug\Windows\Threads).  If the pointer is on the green thread then you are running in the main thread.  If it is on a yellow thread then you are running on a worker thread.

Comment: It runs on a worker thread instead of running on the main thread. So, who is launching the worker thread? The managed Wifi API?

Comment: @BSchlinker If you are creating the `WlanNotificationEventHandler` instance from the main thread then yes, the Managed Wifi API is causing the event to fire on a worker thread.  Actually, it is probably creating a worker thread to periodically check the network connection and when a change is detected the worker thread starts executing the methods which are subscribed to the event.

Answer (score 1):

As an option, alternative...

If I were you, and since you're starting anew anyway, I would seriously consider the
[Rx Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609)

It gives a completely fresh look at events and event based programming and helps a lot exactly with the things you're dealing with (including synchronizing, dealing with threads, combining events, stopping, starting etc. etc.).

It might be a bit of a 'steep curve' to learn at start, but again, it might be worth it.

hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

*To me* it seems that you're going to overengineer the project. 
You basically need to implement an event in `Commander` and in main application subscribe to them. That is.

If there is always one component can make a change and you can have more then one, using some sync mechanism, like a `Mutex` noted by you, is perfectly valid choice.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have at most one state change pending at any time it is probably best to have the event handlers of the external events you are listening to hold a lock during their execution. This ensure an easy way to program because you are guaranteed that the state of your app does not change underneath you. A separate thread is not needed in this particular case.

You need to make a distinction between the current state of the application and the target state. The user dictates the target state ("connected", "disconnected"). The actual state might be different. Example: the user wants to be disconnected but the actual state is authenticating. Once the authentication step is completed the state machine must examine the target state:

```
targetState == connected => set current state to connected
targetState == disconnected => begin to disconnect and set state to disconnecting
```

Separating actual and target state allows the user to change his mind any time and the state machine to steer towards the desired state.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a precise answer without seeing the whole (proposed) structure of your app. But in general, yes, it's OK to use an event hander for that sort of thing - though I'd probably move the actual implementation out to a separate method, so that you can more easily trigger it from other locations.

The comment about disabling the "Connect" button sounds right on to me, though it's quite conceivable you might need other forms of synchronization as well. If your app doesn't need to be multi-threaded, though, I'd steer away from introducing multiple threads just for the sake of it. If you do, look into the new Task API's that have been included as part of the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx). They abstract a lot of that stuff fairly well.

And the comment about not over-thinking the issue is also well-taken. If I were in your shoes, just beginning with a new language, I'd avoid trying to get the architecture just right at the start. Dive in, and develop it with the cognitive toolset you've already got. As you explore more, you'll figure out, "Oh, crap, this is a much better way to do that." And then go and do it that way. Refactoring is your friend.